# Same data, different results when using PARTITION BY and ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have been attempting to write a script to find duplicate records. 
However this will require one of the fields to be the same and the other one to be different. I am using the below 2 lines in my SELECT.

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col_1 ORDER BY col_2) AS 'ROWNUMBER',
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col_2 ORDER BY col_1) AS 'ROWNUMBER2',
```

Once this has been used I then select my results from a TEMP table where both columns are > 1. Now this has produced my results to be correct in one environment however when running the same script in another environment (backup from the weekend) my results are different.

Can some explain to me why this could happen?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the full query, and are you saying that one query works while the other does not, or something else?

Comment: If your goal is to find duplicates, I can give you a working query instead of this one. But If you goal is to correct your approach, please provide your table structure, and explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Haytem, I will be more than happy to try another work around. It was just something i found.

Comment: You want to find any duplicate record? Because your statement *"However this will require one of the fields to be the same and the other one to be different"* doesn't rhyme with that. A duplicate record is one where either one of the fields is different, or both.

Comment: Maybe the results are different because the data is different

Comment: Haha I wish it was :p. I've checked all the data and it is identical unfortunately

Comment: Different collations on the servers? One is case sensitive - the other isn't?

Comment: That is just one strange definition / implementation of duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using row_number? This is not necessary at all, you should use group by:

```
SELECT col_1,col_2 from YourTable
group by col_1,col_2 having count(*) > 1
```

this query will return all duplicated rows

Edit: If you have a 3rd column which you are deciding who is a dup according to it, you should do:

```
SELECT col_3 from yourTable
group by col_3 from yourTable having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Hi Sagi, the reason is because i need a 3rd column which is my primary key and then it throws the grouping off unfortunately :/

Comment: Well, thats your mistake, you didn't tell us what you need to do.. Whe for 3rd columns there are more then two records you want it to flag duplicated? or?.. give us data sample and expected result and i'll fix my query

Comment: Yes I would like it to flag the duplicated record.

Comment: Please edit your post and add input and desires out put example